# Enable/Disable xl2tpd when connecting to specific VPNs

Tags: network-manager, vpn, l2tp

G'day,

I'm an MSP and I'm in the process of trying to use Linux for my daily driver and I tend to need to connect to a lot of different VPNs. My current hurdle is that I have a particular L2TP VPN connection to a Cisco Meraki MX84 at a clients office and I connect using network-manager-l2tp-gnome however it refuses to connect to the if I have xl2tpd running, and while the other L2TP VPN's I have set up that don't connect to Cisco Hardware do require xl2tpd.

Currently my workaround is to run the following when connecting to this specific VPN

```
sudo systemctl stop xl2tpd
```

then when I'm finished, or need to connect to a different VPN, starting xl2tpd back up.

Just to clarify, all the VPNs I have set up function fine if xl2tpd is in the correct state.

Is there a way I can bypass xl2tpd for this one VPN without affecting the others? Or failing that, automatically enable/disable Xl2tpd when I connect/Disconnect this one VPN.

If all else fails I'll just make a quick and dirty script to start and stop the service as needed but I'm just sure there must be a better way.

Currently Running PopOS!_ Ubuntu 19.10 eoan & VPN's are set up via network-manager-l2tp-gnome.